# How to make an office file always open in Protected View?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

Usually when office files (e.g docx, xlsx, pptx etc) are downloaded from the internet and opened, these files open in ***Protected View***.

[image: ProtectedView]

How can I set the default setting of a particular local document to always open in *Protected View*? 

A naive approach is to upload it somewhere and then download it! But is this somehow possible without that?

**P.S:** I am not asking about making a file "*Read-Only*".

Answer (score 2):

Based on information available from the [Microsoft Website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-is-Protected-View-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653) - you have 2 options:

1. Manually opening the office program, and then open the document and selecting "Open as Protected View" - Which is NOT available on Mac version of Office.
2. Set the "Trusted Location" to nothing (On Office 2016 there is a button saying "Disable All Trusted Locations".

To set the trusted location, click on Options - Trust Center - Trust Center Settings - Trusted Locations - Disable All Trusted Locations.

Note: These are settings found on Office 2016 so I can't say for 100% sure if it is available on Office 2013. And also none of these are available on Office for Mac (at least if it is - I can't find it yet)