# How to open Powerpoint slides in read-only or protected view by default? (Windows 10, Office 365 version 2107)

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, office365, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

How can I open all open Powerpoint presentations in read-only or protected-view by default -allowing me to enable editing and saving if I wish once open?

PptView is gone now :-(

Shift+right-click "Open as Read-only" doesn't seem to work at all
Shift+right-click "Open in Protected View"seems to work ok sometimes
(How do I use "Open in Protected View" by default?)

I don't want to set options such as "final" or "read only" or set Sharepoint options for each file ... i want this to happen for all Powerpoint files when i open them. (Local files and files from Sharepoint/Ondrive)

The options in [How to open Office 365 documents in "Viewing" mode by default?](https://superuser.com/questions/1553698/how-to-open-office-365-documents-in-viewing-mode-by-default) assume the file always comes from sharepoint, or requires each file to be modifies to readonly.

If I use "Trust Center" "File Block Settings" I can't save the file even after enabling editing (for local files)

If I try https://gist.github.com/yoshimov/1253177 I cannot save the file - can only save-as

The solutions at [How to make an office file always open in Protected View?](https://superuser.com/questions/1146139/how-to-make-an-office-file-always-open-in-protected-view) and [Shift+Right Click to Open .pptx as Read-Only?](https://superuser.com/questions/841485/shiftright-click-to-open-pptx-as-read-only) have no effect.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it can help you.
Generally, Office files opened from unsafe locations will be opened in protected view. We can try to use "**Group Policy**" to add the unsafe locations:

- Search **Group Policy** in search bar, select Edit group policy to open it.
- Go to *User Configuration>Administrative Templates>Microsoft Office 2016>Security
  Settings>Trust Center>Protected View* to add the unsafe locations.

*（If there is no Microsoft Office 2016 under Administrative Templates, please [download and add Administrative Template files for Office 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49030) first. ）*

In my test, I added the desktop folder as an unsafe location, and checked "**Allow sub folders**" option. After enabling this policy, all Office files on the desktop will be opened in protected view by default.
[image]

Comment: Super. This works perfect for all **local** files  :-) 

But doesn't seem to work for files in **synced Onedrive/Sharepoint** folders. Maybe I need some special path? For me those folders appear in `c:\Users\myname\SharepointServerName\...`
I added an untrusted location `c:\Users\myname` (_with subfolders_) and `c:\Users\myname\SharepointServerName` (_with subfolders_) and `c:\ ` (_with subfolders_).